# What is the URL supposed to be for placing a voice call in twilio API?

Tags: python, twilio

In the sample code for making an outbound call, one of the parameters is URL. Where is the documentation for WHAT is supposed to be in the content of this URL? When I answer the call all i get is we are sorry API error.

```
call = client.calls.create(to="+14155551212",
                           from_="+15017250604",
                           url="http://demo.twilio.com/docs/voice.xml")
```

Comment: Looks like URL should point to a "TwilML" file which describes the text read and sound files played, among other things. https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, apparently using github for the XML causes a bad gateway. So I discovered I can host TwiML using a TwiML Bin. This now generates the correct message.

https://www.twilio.com/console/dev-tools/twiml-bins/